# How to run this function over a table?

Tags: r

I have a function that creates a check column, with a string if there is a value, and a different string for NA. I want to run this function over a table, however I can't work out how.
An extra, the current function needs the colnames argument as a "", is it possible to take non "" like tidyverse functions?

I tried to use `apply` but how does it know the colnames? I want to have a function that would run across every column, or it not possible take a vector of colnames.

```r
library(dplyr)

# Use mtcars dataset
cars = datasets::mtcars

# Add some NA
cars[1, 5] <- NA
cars[2, 4] <- NA


# Create Function
create_check = function(x , y){

names = as.character(y)  
name_col <- paste0(names, "error")

mutate(x, name_col = ifelse(is.na(get(names)), paste0(names," is wrong"), "NA" ))

}
```

The output should be an new column saying NA or a string(e.g "drat is wrong"), so if there are 10 columns then 10 new columns would be created. The new colname should be the name of the column over which NA where searched and the word "error".

```
    hp drat  wt      qsec vs am  gear carb   hp error       drat error     ...
1  110  NA   2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4      NA            drat is wrong  
2  NA  3.90  2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4      hp is wrong   NA
3  93  3.85  2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1      NA            NA
```

help please?

Comment: Please show what your expected output is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `anyNA` to check to see if a column has an NA value.  To apply it across you data set

```
cars = datasets::mtcars
# Add some NA
cars[1, 5] <- NA
cars[2, 4] <- NA
out <- lapply(cars, anyNA)
```

The vector `out` has a subset of which columns have NAs.  The cars dataframe is tidy data, where each row corresponds to a car, so of course you can't just stick a vector referring to which variables have an NA onto it.  If you want  to use your paste command though you can do something like this:

```
ifelse(names(cars) %in% names(cars)[out == TRUE], paste0(names(cars), " is wrong"), "NA" )
```

Comment: @Grey Thank you for your answer, however I didn't give enough detail. I need to identify rows with missing values, not columns. I've added to the question to clarify what i need. Any idea?